# iPhone Socket Inquiry

Tags: iphone, sockets

I am fresh guy in iPhone SDK. I am learning on building a socket communication application between iPhone and Mac. Since I have not used Objective-C before, the work is quite difficult to me. 
Could anybody post a sample code of socket communication application please? Thanks!

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific as to how you see this socket layer working? The iOS developer centre has some sample apps but i don't think they've got much in the way of a custom server on the mac side. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Sample%20Code

Answer (score 0):

Objective C is a superset of ANSI C.  So you can use most any example code in posix C of socket communication.